# How to use "import oauth2" in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, oauth, tumblr

I want to use Tumblr's API v2, which includes OAuth. so I need to find a OAuth module.

I am supposed to use it like this:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
```

I have found the oauth2 source code here: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

1. If I want to use it in my Linux Ubuntu 10.08, whats the process? I have installed git. I notice that there is a "setup.py", so I just have to run it? The ReadME https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/README.md doesnt mention how to install, maybe it is too newbie.
2. If I want to use it in Google App Engine, how can I do it?

Thanks for your help. I am pretty new to GIT stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu, simply `sudo apt-get install python-oauth2` and the package will be installed for you automatically.

For AppEngine, you might take a look at the [Google API Python Client's](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/) appengine examples. They have an OAuth2 client specifically designed to work with AppEngine.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package python-oauth2` I am on Ubuntu 10.08

Comment: Ah, looks like it's only available as a package in natty and later - http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python-oauth2